# iosアプリの互換性の設定を修正したい

Tags: swift, ios, xcode

iosアプリをリリースしているのですが、App Storeの互換性の欄が以下のように、iPhone5s以降になってしまいます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

以下のようにiPhone全般に対応するようにしたいです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

architectureは、armv7, arm64、valid architectureは、arm64、armv7, armv7sが設定されています。
info.plistのUIRequiredDeviceCapabilitiesは何も設定されていない状態です。

どのように修正すれば、上記の互換性に関して設定を変更できるのでしょうか。
よろしくお願いします。

追記
xcodeのバージョンは7.3.1です。

iPhoneOS9.3.sdk - iOS 9.3 (iphoneos9.3)
SDKVersion: 9.3

特記事項
１ビルドをiTunesConnectにアップロードする際にビットコードに関するエラーが出てしまうため、include bitcodeのチェックを外してアップロードしています。
２質問させていただいた何日か後に、全く同じビルドをバージョンを上げて申請したところ、iPhone全般に対応するように改善されました。
しかし、原因が分からないのでまたバージョンアップした時に互換性がiPhone5s以降になってしまわないか、またそうなった時にiPhone5ですでにダウンロードされたものに影響がないか不安です。
何か、お分かりでしたらよろしくお願いします。

Comment: フツーに、下のようになりますが。まずは、XcodeとSDKバージョンおよび、他に、自分のビルド環境について、特記事項がないか、記述した方が良いでしょう。

Comment: 追記が遅くなってしまい申し訳ありません。よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

上と下の対象機種の差は、iPhone4s, iPhone5, iPhone 5c, iPad2, iPad 3,iPad 4, iPad mini, iPod Touch 5genが除外されていることです。

これらは、いずれも、A7以前のプロセッサで、64bit code　executionが出来ません。
　つまり、BITCODEの設定は、大いに関係あるでしょう。今は、BITCODEはデフォルトでオンですが、BITCODEをオフにしないといけない理由は、バイナリの3rd party libraryを使っていて、それが、BITCODE対応でないくらいしかないと思います。
　可能であれば、BITCODEをオフにする設定を外したほうが、いいでしょう。